# problema con metodos statics: non static method cannot be referenced from a static contex

Tags: java

tengo un problema con unos metodos que me tira error "non static method cannot be referenced from a static context" cuando mando a agregar a la lista a un jugador
este es el codigo en que se piden los datos y se manda a la clase sistema los datos para agregar el jugador, se encuentra en la clase interfaz:

```
 public static void registrarJugadores() {
    int edad = 0;
    String nombre;
    String alias;
    Scanner jugadores = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre");
    nombre = jugadores.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese edad");
    //para pedir la edad uso una excepcion para evitar que se caiga el programa en caso de que no se ingrese un numero
    boolean correcto = false;
    while (!correcto) {
        try {
            edad = jugadores.nextInt();
            correcto = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("reingrese su edad en numeros");
            jugadores.nextLine();
        }
    }
    //limpio el scanner
    jugadores.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese alias");
    alias = jugadores.nextLine();
    Jugador j = new Jugador(nombre, edad, alias);
    System.out.println(Sistema.agregarAlista(j));
    System.out.println("presione 1 para registrar otro jugador, 0 para volver al menu principal");
    int respuesta = jugadores.nextInt();
    if (respuesta == 1) {
        registrarJugadores();
    } else {
        menuPrincipal();
    }
}
```

luego esta la clase sistema que es donde tengo el metodo agregarALista():

```
public String agregarAlista(Jugador jugador) {
    boolean existeYa = false;
    String ret = "";
    if (listaJugadores.isEmpty()) {
        listaJugadores.add(jugador);
        ret = "jugador registrado";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaJugadores.size(); i++) {
            if (listaJugadores.get(i).getAlias().equals(jugador.getAlias())) {
                existeYa = true;
            }
        }
        if (!existeYa) {
            listaJugadores.add(jugador);
            ret = "Jugador agregado";
        } else {
            ret = "alias ya existente";
        }
    }
    return ret;

}
```

el error que me tira es exactamente en la linea:

```
System.out.println(Sistema.agregarAlista(j));
```

Comment: El error es claro: *`non static method cannot be referenced from a static context`*  es decir, un método no estático no puede ser usando en un contexto estático. En este caso, `registrarJugadores()` es estático, y desde él intentas usar `agregarAlista()` que no es estático. **Sólo por probar**, si pones este último método como estático el error se resuelve, pero OJO, analiza a fondo el significado del problema para decidir a conciencia cuáles métodos deben ser estáticos en tu modelo de datos y cuáles no. No recurras a soluciones a la ligera sin tener claro por qué debe ser estático o no serlo.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, unos estudiantes de nivel mas avanzado me recomendaron no colocar tantos metodos static por eso no lo habia empleado

Comment: La cuestión no es tener más o tener menos. Si tienes un modelo de datos que amerita tener 1000 métodos estáticos pues tienes los 1000 y si el modelo amerita 1 o 5 o ninguno, pues 1 o 5 o ninguno. La cuestión es que comprendas sus características y tengas claro cuando conviene usarlos y cuando no, según la aplicación que estés desarrollando. Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2671496/5587982), te ayudarán a formarte un criterio al respecto.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Non-static method 'age()' cannot be referenced from a static context](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490097/non-static-method-age-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)